# php - simpleXML trying to understand what is using memory

Tags: php, simplexml

Situation.
I download and process multiple xml files. Download the first file.

Open it with `$xml_file = simplexml_load_file( dirname(__FILE__). '/_downloaded_files/filename.xml' );`

Go through the file, create variables to insert into mysql, insert into mysql. Do the same with next xml files.

After i processed the opened xml file, i unset (set null) variables. Like `$xml_file = null;` Tried also like `unset($xml_file);`, saw no difference. Somewhere found advice to use `gc_enable(); gc_collect_cycles();`, also no difference (no effect).

After executed mysql code, also set to null all used variables.

As result with `echo '<pre>', print_r(get_defined_vars(), true), '</pre>';` saw like

```
[one_variable] => 
[another_variable] => 1
```

I saw many (~ 100) variables with empty content (or one short value for the a variable).

But with `echo (memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024);` see `38.01180267334 MiB memory used`.

Can someone advice where is problem? ~100 empty variables can not use 38 megabytes... What else may use the memory?

Comment: You can try to debug it with xdebug, that will explain the usage hopefully.

Comment: How big is your xml file?  `memory_get_peak_usage ` shows the maximum memory usage during script execution, so it may show memory usage while xml file is loaded in RAM

Comment: The biggest is 10.2 Mb, then 7.2MB, then 1.5MB. But i set to null variable with xml file content. And problem starts when i process 10,2 Mb file. Before that file i process the smaller files and see that uses ~ 6 Mb memory.

Comment: Don't **make** this a problem. The garbage collector manages the memory releasing when necessary. It could be performance wise better to keep the memory reserved, even if not used **now** in the process, but later.

Comment: ... 38 Mb at the moment not very critical, but if i will need to process some additional  xml files and i could not understand what is using the memory, then it will be a problem... ok, will see latter, may be will find solution